# Send file with flask and return a data without refreshing the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I'm developing a web application that takes a grayscale input and return a colorized version of that image using machine learning. For that, the web app is with a python backend linking the front end html pages using the Flask microframework.
I'm sending the image I choose to process in python and then return the image name to display it from its directory. My question is how can I make the previous operations happen without reloading the html page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a minimal working example, which does the exact thing you're asking:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, jsonify, url_for
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

if not os.path.isdir("/static"):  # just for this example
    os.makedirs("/static")

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        fname = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save('static/' + fname)
        # do the processing here and save the new file in static/
        fname_after_processing = fname
        return jsonify({'result_image_location': url_for('static', filename=fname_after_processing)})

    return render_template_string('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
  <label>Some user provided information</label>
  <input type="text" name="some_info" size="12" maxlength="32" /><br />
  <label>File to upload:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload the file!" />
</form>
<img id="resultimg" scr="">
<div></div>
<script>
var form = document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  var oData = new FormData(form);
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "{{url_for('index')}}", true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('resultimg').setAttribute('src', JSON.parse(oReq.responseText).result_image_location);
    } else {
      alert("Error " + oReq.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file")
    }
  };
  oReq.send(oData);
  ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
''')


app.run()
```

I'm not checking for file extensions or overwriting files, so you should secure this feature quite a bit more. But the basic infrastructure is there.

Comment: You the boss man, thank you so much :D , just one question, what's the use of 'oReq.status == 200'

Comment: It checks if the server (flask) is sending the right response. See [this link](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html).

Comment: Thank you again :)